# ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'semPlot'

Tags: r

```
* installing *source* package 'semPlot' ...
** package 'semPlot' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'mi'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'semPlot'
* removing 'C:/Users/Transportation/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/semPlot'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘semPlot’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I solve the problem of ‘semPlot’ installation?
What is the reason for not installing the ‘semPlot’ package?

Comment: Install package `mi` by hand, i.e. `install.packages(c("mi", "semPlot"))`.

Comment: The `there is no package called 'mi'` part of the error message you pasted is a place to start.